Optimising a function (and its routing) consisting of compositions of other functions and modules
A spiking neural network with random connections can be viewed as a non-local cellular automaton where the neurons are the cells and related cells may not be adjacent to each other. Activations are the equivalent of placing a cell on. But a piano piece on a musical keyboard shares just these features. The spiking network consists of nodes that may either activate at the same time or activate in a sequence, while a musical piece is a musical keyboard with notes that may either be played at the same time (as in a chord) or played in a sequence (as in a melody).
The connections of a musical piece on a keyboard are governed by the circle of fifths and fourths or in general by music theory. I believe that music theory decouples the choice of chords and melodies to the maximum, that is why it works. I believe doing that produces the most harmonious and melodious choices as a coincidence.
I want to use the music group to order the activations of a spiking neural network. I will label the nodes as keys on a keyboard. So there will be a $d$ node and a $c$ sharp node as well as a $g_2$ node for the second occurrence of $g$ in the network after we name them modulo $12$ as keys. Then when the neurons at one time step fire, I calculate the perceptual consonance of the keys they represent and proportionate the weight changes of the network by $rc + r$, where $r$ is the global reward and $c$ is the consonance. This way we will only consider being more consonant if it increases the expected reward. Ordinarily in a reward modulated spiking network weight changes are proportioned by just $r$.
Additionally, between time steps we will form connections between nodes that are a musical fifth apart and weaken those of nodes that are not till a point where we break the connection.
I believe that this algorithm produces the optimal routing for a function consisting of functions in a modular and compositional manner. As well as the lowest loss possible with that number of modules.
If this is true, if we optimised a spiking network with the same number of neurons as the human brain like this we would rediscover the brain's routing if it (the brain) is indeed optimal for solving its loss.
I'm looking for a way to prove that this way of optimising the modules and compositions of functions in a function of functions leads us to the optimal routing and optimal way to learn weights for reducing the loss of a network. As well as to produce the time and memory complexity for the algorithm, please. I can reference the person who helps.

I believe the proof is in the decoupling that the algorithm does within and between modules and compositions.
